# How many rationals for a given $n \in \Bbb N \;\backslash \{1\}$?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, rational-numbers, number-systems

Fix $n \in \Bbb N,  n> 1$. Now choose a two digit base-$n$ number $ab $ say. There's $n^2$ choices for this.

Consider the number $0.c_1 c_2 c_3  \ldots$ where the $c_i$ are defined recursively:

$c_1:= a$, $c_2:=b $ and
$c_i:= c_{i-1}+c_{i-2} \pmod n $

First note that this number is rational. There can be at most $n^2$ different two digit numbers found in the expansion, paired as $c_i c_{i+1}$. Therefore by the digit $c_{n^2+1}$ all pairs are exhausted so it must recur at worst by this point. In fact because the way the digits are related it has a period which starts with $c_1$.

Now here's the **question**. Suppose we have two rational numbers $p, q$ defined in the above way with $p=\overline{p_1 p_2\ldots p_k}$ and $q= \overline{q_1 q_2\ldots q_k} $ for some $k$ in $\Bbb N$. Then we say $p\sim q$, $p$ is related to $q$ if $ p_1 p_2\ldots p_k $ is a cyclic permutation of $q_1 q_2\ldots q_k$.

How many distinct rationals are there for a given $n$ with respect to the equivalence relation $\sim$? Suppose $\rho$ is a function which gives the number of solutions for a given $n$, what is $\rho (n)$?

**Eg. $n=2$**

There are four possible numbers
$0$, $0.\overline {011}$, $0.\overline{101}$, $0.\overline {110} $. The last three however are equivalent. Thus $\rho (2)=2$.

It's easy to show by hand that $\rho (3)=2$, $\rho (4)=4$, $\rho (5)=3$, $\rho (6)=4$, $\rho (7)=4$, $\rho (8)=8$.

Wondering if there's a way to predict this.

Comment: So, you have to count the number of strings in n digit strings that satisfy $a_i + a_{i+1} = a_{i+2} \mod n$ with the equivalence relation of cyclic permutation. The "rational" things are there for a reason? Does it help?

Comment: @penasraul Maybe the tag doesn't. I just liked the convenient notation of recurring digits. I think originally I was curious about what rationals they were but that seems cumbersome and unnecessary too tbh. I found this sketched on an old bit of paper in my room while I was tidying

Comment: @penasraul I can replace rational with string the whole way through and drop the $0.$ If you like?

Comment: I was just trying to solve the problem, and asked myself "why the racionals? I must have done something wrong..."

Comment: @penasraul that's a fair point, apologies. Cheers for the feedback so far.

Comment: If you have a list like 2,2,4,3,4,4,8, you type it in the OEIS and [see what you get](https://oeis.org/A015134) ;-)

Comment: @kundor I always forget about the oeis!

Comment: There's also a ton of relevant info on [this page](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fib.htm), including references at the beginning and end.